# "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" when trying to build an embed

Tags: discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot and in this piece of code is showing the error below, instead of sending the embed.

```js
case 'embed':
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .addField('Player Name:', message.author.username);
  message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
  break;
```

> Cannot read property 'username' of undefined"
>    error in the console

Comment: It's pretty weird that a message has no author property: try to use `console.log(message)` before you create the embed and see what it logs.

Comment: @FedericoGrandi **Hey! First of all, thanks for fixing my question's formatting.** When I type **console.log(message)** it brings up **bunch of information** about **message**.

Comment: Do you see any `author` property? Also, which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that message is a Discord.js Message ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could be improved on this. First of all, `RichEmbed` is deprecated. You can use `MessageEmbed` to send an embed. Second, for v12, it does require you to state the field variables. Third, the sendEmbed function is deprecated, using .send(embed) is the updated way. With these points in mind, here is the code

```js
const MessageEmbed = require('discord.js') // This allows you to not have to put 'Discord.' before MessageEmbed

case 'embed':
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .addField(name: 'Player Name:', value: `${message.author.tag}`, inline: true); // ${var} allows the embed to see the username and put it as plain text
  message.channel.send(embed);
  break;
```